# Strange issue with UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a strange issue with memory of UIViewController.

Consider the following scenario wherein i have **ViewController A** that is part of a navigation stack and is a subclass of Another ViewController **SuperA**.

Consider another **ViewController B** that is a subclass of **SuperB**.

I push and pop **ViewController B** after some particular action in **ViewController A**.
In both the ViewControllers i am using NSNotificationObservers for some event.
Whenever an event is fired,even though if i am not in ViewController B i am still able to receive the event in ViewController B.

1. Navigation Stack doesn't show that **ViewController B**.
2. If there is no **ViewController B** in Navigation stack,where does this particular **ViewController B** exist?
3. How do i remove/dispose this **ViewController B**? Also i believe this is due to the SuperB which doesnt get deallocated? Am i right?

Comment: You are correct - in all likelihood ViewController B is not getting deallocated. A frequent culprit are retain cycles, where two objects have a strong relationship with each other and when one tries to deallocate it cannot because another object exists that is holding on to it. A common cause is having a non-weak delegate. Another possibility, depending on the version of iOS, is the NSNotification observers - these should be removed in the complementary `UIViewController` lifecycle phase - e.g., if set up in `viewWillApppear`, they should be removed in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: I tried writing a dummy app that does the above scenario and strangely this only happens in Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter is a centralised hub that enables the broadcast of information to registered observers. Each time an event occurs, the notification goes through its dispatch table, and messages any registered observers for that event.

Notification observers are Strong in reference by default and these observer are not deallocated by default because of strong reference. So, remove it's strong reference when you leave UIViewController.

Code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "name"), object: nil)
}
```

Hope, it will help you.